# Websphere MQ - error with reason code 2042 on a get

Tags: c++, ibm-mq, suse

We're getting an intermittent error on a `ImqQueue::get( ImqMsg &, ImqGetMessageOptions & );` call with reason code 2042, which Should Not Happen™ based on the Websphere documentation; we should only get that reason code on an open.

Would this error indicate that the *server* could not open a queue on its side, or does it indicate that there's a problem in our client?  What is the best way to handle this error?  Right now we just log that it occurs, but it's happening a *lot*.  Unfortunately I'm not well-versed in Websphere MQ; I'm kind of picking this up as I go, so I don't have all the terminology correct.

Our client is written in C++ linking against libmq 6.0.2.4 and running on SLES-10.  I don't know the particulars for the server other than it's running version 7.1.  We're requesting an upgrade to bring our side up-to-date.  We have multiple instances of the client running concurrently; all are using the same request queue, but each is creating its own dynamic reply queue with `MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE + MQOO_INPUT_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING`.

Answer (score 1):

If the queue is not already open, the ImqQueue::get method will implicitly open the queue for you. This will end up with the MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF option being used which will therefore use the DEFSOPT(EXCL|SHARED) attribute on the queue. You should also double check that the queue is defined SHARE rather than NOSHARE, but I suspect that will already be correctly set.

You mention that you have multiple instances of the application running concurrently so if one of them has the queue opened implicitly as MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF resulting in MQOO_INPUT_SHARED from DEFSOPT, then it will get 2042 (MQRC_OBJECT_IN_USE) if others have it open. If nothing else had it open at the time, then the implicit open will work, and later instances will instead get the 2042.

If it is intermittent, then I suggest there is a path through your application where ImqQueue::open method is not invoked. While you look for that, changing the queue definition to DEFSOPT(SHARED) should get rid of the 2042s.